# nunjuck filter for remove diacritics

Tags: nunjucks

Portuguese makes use of five diacritics: the cedilla (ç), acute accent (á, é, í, ó, ú), circumflex accent (â, ê, ô), tilde (ã, õ), and grave accent (à, and rarely è, ì, ò, and ù). The cedilla indicates that ç is pronounced /s/ (from a historic palatalization).

When searching, removing the diacritics and convert to uppercases like :  á, é, í, ó, ú -> A E I  O U

Are there any nunjucks filter for this job?

{{ content_with_diacritics | filter_for_search }}

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you looking for [replace](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#replace) filter. Call it multile times with required replacements.